# How can I update an Access table with a DataRow in a DataTable I just created?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

```
sSql = "SELECT * FROM tblTicketChanges"
Dim dtChg As DataTable = CreateDataTable(sSql, con)
```

I create the row in the code below and then add it to a datatable created above called dtChg.

```
Public Sub ADOSave2ChangeList(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByRef sFld As String, ByRef sNewValu As String, ByRef sOldValu As String, ByRef sTicketNo As String, ByRef sQualifier As String, ByRef sUser As String, ByRef dDate As Date, ByRef varTime As Date)
    Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow                                                            ' Add new change record

    r("ChangeTime") = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy} {1:hh:mm:ss}", dDate, varTime)    ' Change date and time
    r("Division") = gDiv                                                              ' Division number
    r("Location") = gLocation                                                         ' Location id
    r("TicketNo") = sTicketNo                                                         ' Ticket number
    r("Qualifier") = NoNull(sQualifier)                                               ' Qualifier
    r("FieldName") = sFld                                                             ' Name of field that changed
    r("OriginalValue") = sOldValu                                                     ' Original value
    r("NewValue") = sNewValu                                                          ' New value
    r("ChangedByUser") = sUser                                                        ' User id

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", r.ItemArray))

    dt.Rows.Add(r)                                                                          ' Save changes

    gChanged = True                                                                                 ' Flag that change happened
End Sub
```

Is there a way to update or insert intothe Access table with the datatable dtChg without an sql insert statement? Or a way to just add that new row to the Access table without using the sql statement?

Comment: Have a read up on data adapters.  Hides the implementation of inserts/updates/selects

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the OleDbCommandBUilder:

```
  Dim Builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da2)
            Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
            da2.UpdateCommand = Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
            da2.Update(ds, "Changes")
```

I will add that I had to dimension a DataSet and I also named the DataTable "Changes".
I not quite sure what is going on with the CommandBUilder but it seems pretty powerful. Going to read up on it.